# Run model in reverse in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm currently playing around with the Keras framework. And have done some simple classification tests, etc. I'd like to find a way to run the network in reverse, using the outputs as inputs and vice versa. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "running a neural net in reverse", as a generic architecture of neural net **does not define any not-forward data processing**. There is, however, a subclass of models which do - the generative models, which **are not a part of keras** right now. The only thing you can do is to create a network which somehow "simulates" the generative process you are interested in. But this is paricular model specific method, and has no general solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way, but your mileage may vary, and it might just return rubbish at the input, although that 'rubbish' will still produce the output you're starting from. The key phrase is 'treat inputs as weights and train them with the rest of the model fixed'.

I.e., you can replace the input layer with a layer of weights, freeze the rest of the model and train those weights while fixing the outputs.

To fit this into the fabric of Keras, I created a custom layer and called it 'Recover'. It is not triggered while the model is trained, however it serves as a faux input layer for the reverse training step. (I'm sure the approach can be optimised further, but that's the quickest hack I could come up with).

```py
class Recover(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Recover, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.reverse = False

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1],),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(Recover, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        if self.reverse:
            return K.ones_like(x)*self.kernel
        else:          
            return x

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[0])
```

Add this layer directly after the input layer, set `trainable` to `False` on this layer. First, train the network normally, this layer should be ignored and work as a pass-through.

After this is done, reset weights within this layer, set `reverse` to `True`, `trainable` to `True` for this layer and `trainable` to `False` for all other layers, recompile the model and start training again.

Something along these lines:

```py
for x in model.layers:
    x.trainable = False
model.layers[0].trainable = True
model.layers[0].reverse = True
model.compile( ...your compile parameters... )
```

At this point the actual inputs will be ignored at the time of calling `model.fit`, and one could just specify zeros in the correct shape for the input array.

With this approach sometimes it'll get stuck at a suboptimal solution. Just reinitialise the weights of the `Recover` layer and repeat. After you trained it, the weights of the `Recover` layer can be obtained by calling `get_weights()` and will correspond to the inputs of the original model that will cause it to produce the desired outputs.

The result most likely will be noise-like, and it might be necessary to introduce additional losses (via calling `self.add_loss` inside the `call` function) to coerce the model into producing meaningful inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the use case for this, but just adding on a quick fix, would be to just redesign an architecture, such that inputs were then treated as the outputs and visa-versa.

Assuming your input data is in the shape (as an example):

```
n_obs, n_feat = 1000, 20
n_labels = 2
n_hidden = 100 # you can make this whatever you want
```

You would usually design the input layer like:

```
Dense(input_dim = n_feat, output_dim = n_hidden)
```

And the output layer like:

```
Dense(input_dim = n_hidden, output_dim = n_labels)
```

If you then wanted to run this "in reverse", just make another model, with the opposite architecture, like:

New input layer:

```
Dense(input_dim = n_labels, output_dim = n_hidden)
```

New output layer:

```
Dense(input_dim = n_hidden, output_dim = n_feat)
```

But similar to what lejlot said above, there is not a single model solution here. You cannot train your model on the input data and then test it on the output data. Does this make sense?

The underlying weight matrices have to have the correct dimensions for the data, and the moment you try to give it different shaped data (ie output data in place of the input data), it cannot perform the matrix multiplication, that is at the heart of every Neural Network.

If you're confused on this point, you should review how Neural Networks actually work, under the hood.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this was a while back and I was trying to make an auto encoder. Didn't know what was called so "running a model backwards" was the best I could do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, I think, is the "Auto-Associative" neural network. it has an input of n dimensions, several layers, one of which is the "middle layer" of m dimensions, and then several more layers leading to an output layer which has the same number of dimensions as the input layer, n.

The key here is that m is much smaller than n.

How it works is that you train the network to recreate the input, exactly at the output. Then you cut the network into two halves. The front half goes from n to m dimensions (encoding the input into a smaller space). The back half goes from m dimensions to n dimensions (decoding, or "reverse" if you will).

Very useful for encryption, compression, unsupervised learning, etc.

Comment: P.S. I used to have some of these methods patented, and I sold the patents to Ericsson, but the patents have since expired, so I've published the source code and documentation, Sadly, it's all written in "C" - if you want to go back to the stone age of "C code, when dinosaurs roamed the earth ;-)

Comment: https://github.com/prof-nussbaum/INTEGRAT-reading-the-mind-of-the-AI-robot